# AudioKit custom Waveforms

Tags: waveform, audiokit

It is my chief longing with AudioKit to be able to define my own waveforms for timbre sake.

As far as I have tried, passing a waveform parameter into a new AKOscillator will not actually use that shape of wave, instead we are limited to Square Sine Tri Saw.

Has anyone had any luck getting this feature to work?

Can I see how this is implemented in the source code somehow?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code or which AudioKit version you are on, its hard to debug, but I can vouch for the fact that this work on AudioKit's develop branch and I've never heard of it not working for anyone.

There's a playground demonstrating tables here:
http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Tables/

If you add the following lines you'll hear the custom waveform:

```
let osc = AKOscillator(waveform: custom)
AudioKit.output = osc
osc.start()
try AudioKit.start()
```